# How to UITest labels in xib/nib

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib, nimble

We have a nib with few labels (ex: SubmitterName). This nib is on the view controller that has `tableview`. During our UI Test, we are able to see all the elements from the `tableview`, but we do not see anything from nib. We are using Quick/Nimble.

```
let app = self.app!
expect(app.staticTexts["John Doe"].exists).to(beTrue())
```

This assert fails because it does not find "John Doe", even though it is visible on the controller. Do we need to access our nib first to get all of its elements and then assert? When we do po `app.staticTexts` we see all the text except text from the nib.